# consuming asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have web api deployed to IIS, it works fine when called via browser like: http:// localhost /api/products response is in XML.

But however when i call it via Ajax it doesn't work. Google Chrome returns the following error:

. origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'http://localhost/api/products';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#test").append(data[5].prod);

        });
    });
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the advice here [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin).

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain requests, you should make a jsonp ajax request